# VS code reuses existing window for 'Open recent'

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I do File > Open recent in VS Code, it reuses my current project window to open the new project, and the project I was looking at is gone.

How do I stop it from doing this? I want a new project window for a project I open.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'd searched but not found that.